# npm WARN tarball tarball data for @types/node@^8.0.7 seems to be corrupted

Tags: ionic-framework, ubuntu-18.04

I tried to install ionic with npm and ended up with this error:

```
$ sudo npm install -g ionic
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @types/node@^8.0.7 (sha512-tGVTbA+i3qfXsLbq9rEq/hezaHY55QxQLeXQL2ejNgFAxxrgu8eMmYIOsRcl7hN1uTLVsKOOYacV/rcJM3sfgQ==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for xdg-basedir@^3.0.0 (sha1-SWsswQnsqNus/i3HK2A8F8WHCtQ=) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for superagent@^4.1.0 (sha512-FT3QLMasz0YyCd4uIi5HNe+3t/onxMyEho7C3PSqmti3Twgy2rXT4fmkTz6wRL6bTF4uzPcfkUCa8u4JWHw8Ag==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for ws@^6.0.0 (sha512-GIyAXC2cB7LjvpgMt9EKS2ldqr0MTrORaleiOno6TweZ6r3TKtoFQWay/2PceJ3RuBasOHzXNn5Lrw1X0bEjqA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @ionic/utils-fs@1.2.0 (sha512-31RPQlxfaIPf3QQgHZGLEDPZrf+AQY0CNgReCp+qZ1pm6mWvOerH17QOSylzcun0J3gPBt1EgiTHRcVJrLljPA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for readable-stream@^2.0.2 (sha512-tQtKA9WIAhBF3+VLAseyMqZeBjW0AHJoxOtYqSUZNJxauErmLbVm2FW1y+J/YA9dUrAC39ITejlZWhVIwawkKw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for readable-stream@^2.0.2 (sha512-tQtKA9WIAhBF3+VLAseyMqZeBjW0AHJoxOtYqSUZNJxauErmLbVm2FW1y+J/YA9dUrAC39ITejlZWhVIwawkKw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for rxjs@^6.4.0 (sha512-Z9Yfa11F6B9Sg/BK9MnqnQ+aQYicPLtilXBp2yUtDt2JRCE0h26d33EnfO3ZxoNxG0T92OUucP3Ct7cpfkdFfw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be late would help others landing here

Try `npm cache clean --force`

then `sudo npm install -g ionic`

The problem is with your NPM not ionic

Answer (score 0):

Try removing package-lock.json/yarn.lock and re-do "npm install" for your specific package or for the entire dependencies mentioned in your package.json